# Specifying that hierarchical probability distribution conditional on independent random parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to create a `ParameterMixtureDistribution` to model the following:

$X \sim $ Binomial($N,P$)

$N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda) \perp P \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$

The confusion arises from the specification of independent parameter distributions.  How can I best implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pmd = ParameterMixtureDistribution[BinomialDistribution[n, p], {n, p} \[Distributed] 
        ProductDistribution[PoissonDistribution[λ], BetaDistribution[α, β]]]

Mean[pmd]
```

$ \frac{\alpha  \lambda }{\alpha +\beta } $

```
Variance[pmd]
```

$\frac{\alpha ^3 \lambda +2 \alpha ^2 \beta  \lambda +\alpha ^2 \lambda +\alpha  \beta ^2 \lambda +\alpha 
   \beta  \lambda ^2+\alpha  \beta  \lambda }{(\alpha +\beta )^2 (\alpha +\beta +1)}$